# How can I read a binary file from a post request sent to in Azure Function in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

I am writing an Azure Function in Python that is going to receive binary files, do some processing and then return a different binary. For now I am just trying to create some basic echo functionality. How can I get the binary data sent to via a POST request? Here is what I have been trying, but I always end up getting corrupted data in return.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    img = req.get_body()

    return func.HttpResponse(body=img,mimetype='image/jpg')
```

The POST request is being generated with curl.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:7071/api/my_function_name -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -d @input.jpg > test.jpg
```

test.jpg is always corrupted upon return. I don't know if I am reading it wrong from the request or sending it back wrong in the response (or both).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was looking in the wrong place. My curl was the problem. Use

> --data-binary input.jpg